# Is it possible to get live css/image reloading in grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm currently using [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) which has livereload built in. However, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/blob/master/tasks/lib/livereload.js), it seems a lot more simplified than [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/)'s [livereload-js](https://github.com/livereload/livereload-js), which includes extra features such as live css/image reloading (as opposed to reloading the entire page)

Is it possible to get those features in a grunt task?

Comment: I'm also aware that there is a guard task for it (https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload), so presumably it's possible outside of the official desktop app.

Comment: I never got LiveReload to work realiably. I use this little snippet. To start refreshing just copy/paste in console while you're developing. To stop refreshing press F5. https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/3883731

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v2 of grunt-contrib-watch has livereload built in, as you mentioned. The CSS reloads without a full page reload just fine if you use it in conjunction with the livereload chrome extension (I haven't tried in other browsers).

```
watch: {
    scripts: {
        files: [ 'js/*.js' ],
        options: {
            livereload: true
        }
    },
    html: {
        files:['index.html', 'stylesheets/*.css'],
        options: {
            livereload: true
        }
    }
}
```

Is all the setup you should need.

Comment: I've tested it without the livereload chrome extension, and on firefox, and it works fine too.